# Why am I getting a PHP Fatal error with my code?

Tags: php, mysqli

I have been wracking my brain for hours now trying to figure out why my code is giving me the error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function close() on a non-object in /var/www/Garage/ajaxFunctions/ServiceReplication.php on line 24
```

Here is my code. It is the back end of an AJAX call in my application:

```
<?php
    /*
        Description:
        Parameters:
        Return:
    */
    include_once('../includes/config.inc.php');
    include_once('../includes/dbConnection.php');

    // $newTargetID = (isset($_GET['newTargetID']) && $_GET['newTargetID'] != '') ? strip_tags($_GET['newTargetID']) : null;
    // $service = (isset($_GET['service']) && $_GET['service'] != '') ? strip_tags($_GET['service']) : null;

    $newTargetID = "12988";
    $service = "16468";

    $returnValue = "0";

    if($newTargetID != null && $service != null){
        $ServiceReplicationQuery = "call ServiceReplication(" . $newTargetID . "," . $service . ")";
        error_log("ServiceReplicationQuery: " . $ServiceReplicationQuery);
        if($result = $dbConnection->query($ServiceReplicationQuery)){
            error_log("Successfully replicated service " . $service . " to target " . $newTargetID . ".");
            $returnValue = "1";
            $result->close();
        }
        else{
            error_log("Failure replicating service " . $service . " to target " . $newTargetID . ".");
        }
    }
    else{
        error_log("Failure replicating service " . $service . " to target " . $newTargetID . ".");
    }

    echo $returnValue;
?>
```

Note that the dbConnection.php include does have a valid and working mysqli db connection, and I have other AJAX back ends that are almost identical to this that work perfectly, the only difference is that I am using a stored procedure with this piece of code.

I can take the error_log echo of my query, place it in MySQL Workbench, and it works fine. In fact, even though I get this error, the database is updated. I am just getting this error and not getting the return value I need, which is "1".

Comment: `$dbConnection->close()`. You close the connection, not the result.

Comment: Isn't $result a boolean or data array? I would think that you need to use close() on $dbConnection; $dbConnection->close();

Comment: your query is not returning data thus your if is causing fatal error as you cannot call `close()` on empty (read: non-object) `$result`

Comment: @JohnConde I found this on PHP.net, here http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are erroneously setting a variable instead of comparing it in an if statement:

```
if ($result = $dbConnection->query($ServiceReplicationQuery)) {
```

This will always evaluate to true. The error you get is because you try to call method close() on $result, which is fatal when $result is not an object.

Update your code to this instead of `$result->close()`:

```
$dbConnection->close();
```

Or if you really want to call close on $result:

```
$result = $dbConnection->query($ServiceReplicationQuery)
if ($result) {
```

or this:

```
$result = $dbConnection->query($ServiceReplicationQuery)
if (is_object($result)) {
```

depending on what is more appropriate in what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: `$result` might not always evaluate to true - if the query fails, then it will be set to `false`.

Comment: But ... I have used this method before, lots of times, and it works.

Comment: @andrewsi: Well since we have no idea what query() does or returns, it's all speculating, thus why I have provided 3 possible updates, depending on how the code works :)

Comment: @Brian: check your query then. It is not returning data thus failing. You do not get the error if your query returns something.

Comment: if you still want to catch errors issued by php, use the function [set_error_handler](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.set-error-handler.php)

Comment: Ok, I have changed it to $dbConnection->close(), and it works. I am still confused as to why my other method did not work. You can find an example of this on PHP.net at http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Comment: Your query returns an empty result. You are most likely have mixed IDs or something. Check `$newTargetID` and `$service` vars then.

Comment: I will accept the answer, but I would still like to know why $result->close() does not work here, like it does on the PHP.net example and in all my other code. As an interesting aside, I went and changed all of my $result->close() to $dbConnection->close() and it broke everything.

Comment: Why $result->close() does not work? To say it simply, you get an error when $result is empty (null or just a simple 'string', not an object with close() method)